How to fix 'RestError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.' in Azure file upload
I am trying to upload a file through my backend made with Hono, NeDB, and TS. The following is the request being sent from frontend after file selection:
const res = await axios.post(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL}/files/sas?file=${encodeURIComponent(
        file.name
)}&permission=${permission}&container=${blobStorageSettings.containerName}&timerange=${timerange}`,
{
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('jwt').replace(/"/g, '')
    }
}
)

And the following endpoint at the backend:
files.post("/sas", async (c: Context) => {
  try {
...
        const fileName = c.req.query('file') || 'nonamefile';
        const permissions = c.req.query('permission') || 'w';
        const timerange = parseInt(c.req.query('timerange') || '10'); // 10 minutes by default
        const containerName = blobStorageDetails.containerName || 'anonymous';
        
        const sasUrl = await generateSASUrl(
          blobStorageDetails.serviceName,
          blobStorageDetails.serviceKey,
          containerName,
          fileName,
          permissions,
          timerange
        );
...

generateSASUrl:
export const generateSASUrl = async (
    serviceName: string,
    serviceKey: string,
    containerName: string,
    fileName: string, // hierarchy of folders and file name: 'folder1/folder2/filename.ext'
    permissions = 'r', // default read only
    timerange = 1 // default 1 minute
): Promise<string> => {
    if (!serviceName || !serviceKey || !fileName || !containerName) {
        return 'Generate SAS function missing parameters';
    }

    const blobServiceClient = getBlobServiceClient(serviceName, serviceKey);
    const containerClient = await createContainer(
        containerName,
        blobServiceClient
    );
    const blockBlobClient = await containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(fileName);

    // Best practice: create time limits
    const SIXTY_MINUTES = timerange * 60 * 1000;
    const NOW = new Date();

    // Create SAS URL
    const accountSasTokenUrl = await blockBlobClient.generateSasUrl({
        startsOn: NOW,
        expiresOn: new Date(new Date().valueOf() + SIXTY_MINUTES),
        permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse(permissions), // Read only permission to the blob
        protocol: SASProtocol.Https // Only allow HTTPS access to the blob
    });

    return accountSasTokenUrl;
};

I think the error originates when I try to create the container using the 'createContainer' function:
async function createContainer(
    containerName: string,
    blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient
): Promise<ContainerClient> {
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    console.log("containerClient", containerClient);
    await containerClient.createIfNotExists();
    console.log("Container created");

    return containerClient;
}

The 'containerClient' seems to have been created but the error arises at 'await containerClient.createIfNotExists()':
Error: RestError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.

www-authenticate header:
"www-authenticate": "Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/75df096c-8b72-48e4-9b91-cbf79d87ee3a/oauth2/authorize resource_id=https://storage.azure.com",

For reference I am following the 'Upload an image to an Azure Storage blob' tutorial with the relevant Storage Account configuration and settings available on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/browser-file-upload-azure-storage-blob
I have tried creating the container without the 'containerClient.createIfNotExists()' but that did not help.


RestError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.

The above error occurs when you request with wrong parameters or incorrect permission to access the Azure blob storage.
According to this MS-Document:

You need to upload the blob with required headers. I see in your code you are missing the header x-ms-blob-type = Blockblob.
Check the SAS token is in the correct format. To upload a blob in SAS token, you need read, create and write permission.

Here is the sample code to create a SAS token and upload to Azure blob storage using TypeScript.
Make sure to use the proper request URL to upload to Azure blob storage.
Request:
 PUT https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test/sample345.txt?<Your-sas token>
 Headers: 
 x-ms-blob-type : Blockblob
 and file.


